# Null check on XElement

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

My current project (C# 3.5) has a lot of code like this (elem is an instance of XElement):

```
textbox1.Text = elem.Element("TagName") == null ? "" : elem.Element("TagName").Value;
```

Is there any way to write the same thing without repeating a call elem.Element() and without use of extension methods?
Maybe using lambdas? (But I cannot figure out how.)

Comment: Why do you want to avoid Extension Methods if that's exactly a use-case for them? Alternative (the Java-way) would be to define a static method somewhere, and use that: `ElementHelper.ValueOrDefault(elem, "TagName", "")`.

Comment: @Marcel Jackwerth I just want to know whether there are other ways:)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

XElement has a explicit conversion to String (and [a bunch of other types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx)) that will actually call .Value.
In otherwords you can write this:

```
var value = (String)elem.Element("TagName");
```

i think this will return null if the actual element is null as well

-edit-

verified, 
here is an example:

```
 var x = new XElement("EmptyElement");
 var n = (String)x.Element("NonExsistingElement");
```

`n` will be null after this.

Comment: So - just to state it - the full solution would be `(String)elem.Element("TagName") ?? "";`.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'll stick with this solution.

Comment: Great stuff, saves me doing a null check each time!

Answer (score 7):

Yes. you can write it like this:

```
(string)elem.Element("TagName") ?? "";
```

This is the *null coalescing operator*.

It means that if the left hand side is not null, then use the left hand side. If it is null, then use the right hand side.

Comment: You didn't read the question. If elem.Element("TagName") != null, we need the elem.Element("TagName").Value, not elem.Element("TagName")

Comment: @VMAtm - I reread it now. Still can't see what you are complaining about here. Can you please give some more information regarding what you mean is wrong here?

Comment: Øyvind: The part after the `:` has an additional `.Value`. I stumbled into the same trap.

Comment: @VMAtm & @Joey - Didn't see that one. Fixed my answer now. Verified it on my own system.

Answer (score 2):

There is a great article on the CodeProject for such actions:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/maybemonads.aspx

```
public static TResult With<TInput, TResult>(this TInput o, 
       Func<TInput, TResult> evaluator)
       where TResult : class where TInput : class
{
  if (o == null) return null;
  return evaluator(o);
}

string valueEl = this.With(x => elem.Element("TagName")
                  .With(x => x.Value);
```

Other examples are available on the CodeProject.

Comment: I modified (improved?) this answer by removing the class constraint on the TResult type and returning default(TResult) instead of null.

Answer (score 2):

A crazy `??` approach:

```
// make this a member-variable somewhere
var emptyElement = XElement.Parse("<x></x>");

(elem.Element("TagName") ?? emptyElement).Value;
```

Would have preferred an extension method though.

Answer (score 0):

Have a similar situation to this which has to do with Xml boolean checks and this was my resolution that used the null coalescing operator:

`Convert.ToBoolean(this.xDocument.Root.XPathSelectElement(@"/settings/checkbox[@name = 'MessageArrivedTimeCheckBox']").Value ?? "false");`

The reason being that the xml is understood by default as a string with there being type resolution issues that may be resolvable through serialization parameters within the xml itself, but I doubt even that would be possible because it doesn't understand it until runtime. Maybe there's a declaration or assignment that can be done with the element itself with type expectation?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't apply to the original question, but since it seems this question is still actively viewed, this is an update for C# 6.0+ projects:

Since C# 6.0, using the null-conditional operator (`?.`) and null-coalescing operator (`??`) you can do this:

```cs
textbox1.Text = elem.Element("TagName")?.Value ?? "";
```

Cf. [Null-Conditional Operator Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) and [Null-Coalescing Operator Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator).